# Top app to run the University course classes remotely during a medical epidemic emergency

Tags: education, remote-work

As our University closed most of one week which estimated more than one month, we need to be in contact with each other like the classrooms, so I have spoken by one of our master who was recently in USA in last two months and said there we used the:

1. [Google class](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-classroom/mfhehppjhmmnlfbbopchdfldgimhfhfk)

2. [classroom](https://edu.google.com/products/classroom/?modal_active=none)  app.

So I ask here which one is more professional for running the classes and better for this condition, and if you know more proper method or app to run the courses class in this kind with ability like :

- User friendly and simple usage

-  Have options like using low bandwidth internet and with low-speed internet

- Have ability to ask questions during the live streaming

Comment: Here we use [Zoom](http://zoom.us). It's gratis account have limitations (only 40 minutes of connection), though. Works well enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in China, you can use https://www.ulearning.cn/

We are using it for our university. However, I do not know much about the technical aspect of it because I am just using it as a lecturer.